# What to use for "rain" ? Set on, set off, set in, set down

Tags: verbs

I saw this in an English Level Test. I don't remember the complete sentence. It was like, **bla bla bla** *(here there was something I don't remember)* **really rain ...**

Three dots is where you will use one of the verbs on the title I wrote.

1. What to use for 3 dots in this case?
2. What do other verbs mean and how to use them in a sentence?

Comment: ' ... the rain really set in' ( = ' the rain became heavy and continued for a long time').